# How to start Slick Slider from Left in center mode

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

[image]

Hey Stackoverflow members. I have a slick slider. i want to start from left. Is there any way with centermode: true. Because center is essential. Here is the codepen demo link below. I want slider number 1 to start from left and if it goes to slider 2 it must be on center.

I am trying to create a section like this in Our teams and tools section in this link: https://ware2go.co/our-solution/

[Codepen Demo Link](https://codepen.io/anand-kumar/pen/ZEBjzqy)

```
 $(".center").slick({
        dots: true,
    infinite: false,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
   variableWidth: true
});
```

Comment: well to start from left change centerMode to false.

Comment: `centerMode: false`. No way to center `slide 2` without `center mode` (Simple Math issue). Try first to layout your idea in photoshop (Sound imposibble). Maybe also add a screenshot to your Q (simple copy-paste).

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen. Actually i need the centerMode to be true from slide 2. Because if the image is placed inside it goes left. Is there any other way to make it start from left.

Comment: @Anandkumar yes I know but you need to change that to true when you slide to slide2, so you need to listen for the slide event

Comment: @EzraSiton centerMode: False works. But it goes out of focus of active elements

Comment: It would be helpful if any other sliders available like this.

Comment: I am trying to create a section like this Our teams and Section in this link:https://ware2go.co/our-solution/

Comment: What about `centerMode: true` **and** `infinite: true`? https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/gOLjpVO

Comment: @MoshFeu it shows the last element at first

Comment: The first element is at center - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nys0.png

Comment: @MoshFeu. I want the first element alone to be at left

Comment: Set your `initialSlide` slide to 1?

Comment: What did you end up doing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete HTML, CSS, jQuery Code

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

  jQuery("ul.tabs li").on("click", function(){

    jQuery("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active")

  });

  var slideWidth = jQuery('.tabs').outerWidth()

  jQuery('.tabs').slick({
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 7,
      slidesToScroll: 7,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      variableWidth: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: slideWidth,
      draggable: true,
      swipeToSlide: true,
  });


  jQuery(".tabs .slick-track").addClass("removeTransform");

  jQuery(".tabs .slick-slide").click(function(){

      var getid = jQuery(this).data('slick-index');

      if( getid > 3 ) {
          jQuery(".tabs .slick-track").removeClass("removeTransform");
      }
      else {
          jQuery(".tabs .slick-track").addClass("removeTransform");
      }
  });
  
 });
```

```css
ul.tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.tabs li {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
ul.tabs li.active {
    color: #E7FE78;
    background: #F15E22;
}
ul.tabs .removeTransform {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

 <ul class="tabs">
  <li data-id="fb" class="active">F&B</li>
  <li data-id="social">Social</li>
  <li data-id="web3">Web3</li>
  <li data-id="fecomb">E-Com</li>
  <li data-id="edtech">EdTech</li>
  <li data-id="medtech">MedTech</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech 2</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech 3</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech 4</li>
  <li data-id="social">Social</li>
  <li data-id="web3">Web3</li>
  <li data-id="fecomb">E-Com</li>
  <li data-id="edtech">EdTech</li>
  <li data-id="medtech">MedTech</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech 2</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech 3</li>
  <li data-id="fintech">FinTech 4</li>
</ul>
```